# AdminJs - MongooseError: Operation buffering timed out after 10000ms

Tags: node.js, nestjs, nest, adminjs

I'm attempting to integrate AdminJS with Nest.js.

I can successfully log in to the /admin panel, but when I attempt to access a specific resource, I encounter the following error: "MongooseError: Operation buffering timed out after 10000ms."

Here's a snippet of my package.json file showing the relevant dependencies:

```
    "dependencies": {
      "@adminjs/express": "^6.0.1",
      "@adminjs/mongoose": "^4.0.0",
      "@adminjs/nestjs": "^6.0.1",
      "@nestjs/common": "^9.0.0",
      "@nestjs/core": "^9.0.0",
      "@nestjs/mongoose": "^10.0.1",
      "@nestjs/platform-express": "^9.0.0",
      "@nestjs/swagger": "^7.1.13",
      "adminjs": "^7.3.0",
      "class-transformer": "^0.5.1",
      "class-validator": "^0.14.0",
      "express-formidable": "^1.2.0",
      "express-session": "^1.17.3",
      "mongoose": "^7.6.3",
      "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.13",
      "rxjs": "^7.2.0"
    }
```

And here's a section of my app.module.ts file:

```
(async () => {
  const AdminJSMongoose = await import('@adminjs/mongoose');
  const AdminJS = (await import('adminjs')).AdminJS;

  AdminJS.registerAdapter({
    Resource: AdminJSMongoose.Resource,
    Database: AdminJSMongoose.Database,
  });
})();

const DEFAULT_ADMIN = {
  email: 'admin@example.com',
  password: 'password',
};

const authenticate = async (email: string, password: string) => {
  if (email === DEFAULT_ADMIN.email && password === DEFAULT_ADMIN.password) {
    return Promise.resolve(DEFAULT_ADMIN);
  }

  return null;
};

@Module({
  imports: [
    ConfigModule.forRoot({
      isGlobal: true,
    }),
    // Mongoose connection options: https://mongoosejs.com/docs/connections.html
    MongooseModule.forRoot(process.env.MONGODB_URL),
    // AdminJS version 7 is ESM-only. In order to import it, you have to use dynamic imports.
    import('@adminjs/nestjs').then(({ AdminModule }) =>
      AdminModule.createAdminAsync({
        useFactory: () => ({
          adminJsOptions: {
            rootPath: '/admin',
            resources: [
              {
                resource: model('Question', QuestionSchema),
                options: {
                  navigation: {
                    name: 'Sunrise',
                  },
                  properties: {
                    id: { type: 'string' },
                    text: { type: 'richtext' },
                    options: { type: 'mixed' },
                    correctOptionId: { type: 'string' },
                    image: { type: 'file' },
                    language: { type: 'string' },
                  },
                },
              },
            ],
          },
          auth: {
            authenticate,
            cookieName: 'adminjs',
            cookiePassword: 'secret',
          },
          sessionOptions: {
            resave: true,
            saveUninitialized: true,
            secret: 'secret',
          },
        }),
      }),
    ),
    QuestionsModule,
  ],
  controllers: [AppController],
  providers: [
    AppService,
    { provide: APP_FILTER, useClass: AllExceptionsFilter },
    { provide: APP_FILTER, useClass: HttpExceptionFilter },
    { provide: APP_FILTER, useClass: ValidationFilter },
  ],
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your database is not connecting...

Specifically the line:

```
MongooseModule.forRoot(process.env.MONGODB_URL),
```

Initializes a module for mongoose to connect to the mongodb instance over the network at MONGODB_URL which should be specified as an environment variable.

Are you using something like [dotenv](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv)?

If so, you need MONGODB_URL to be defined in your `.env` file

If not, you need to somehow provide a mongodb url to that "forRoot" function I mentioned before.

If you do not yet have a mongodb database instance running locally or hosted over the internet, I recommend [MongoDB Atlas](https://www.mongodb.com/atlas). (I am not associated in any way it's just what I use because they have a powerful free tier.)

Comment: This is not necessarily an issue with database connectivity. I have the same issue and database is connected and working.